# get the sharePoint sites which the current user has access using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

Using RestAPI, how can i get the All sharePoint sites which the current user has access from the WebAppilication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the search API to get this information, something similar to the following:

```
https://<site_name>.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site
Path:"https://<site_name>.sharepoint.com/*"'
```

The REST API always runs as the logged in user so if the user does not have permission to a site then the API will not return it.